# ERROR: ValueError: Unable to coerce list of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Series/DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, compiler-errors, valueerror

I am getting an unexpected error and not sure what may be causing it. I checked the code over several times and tried changing some parameters but still the same error. Any ideas what I could be missing? The error only seems to happen in the last line in iteration 1.

This is the exact error: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHUez.png)

```
trips_values_fut = {'Ps': [31.0, 38.0, 39.0],
                 'As': [75.0, 14.0, 19.0]
                 }
trips_df = pd.DataFrame(trips_values_fut, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print("\nProjected values of 2041 are:\n", trips_df)

# constructing matrix for travel time
times_dict = {'A': [8.4, 13.2, 25.2],
              'B': [15.8, 8.4, 10],
              'C': [30.2, 12, 8.4]
}
times_df = pd.DataFrame(times_dict, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print("\nTravel times are: \n", times_df)

# Impedance function
beta = -0.064
grav = np.exp(beta*times_df)
print("\nImpedance Function:\n", grav)

# Iteration 0
Os_i = grav.sum(axis='columns')  # sum of impedance function rows
Ds_j = grav.sum(axis='index')  # sum of impedance function columns
O_i = trips_df['Ps']  # Projected Trip Origins in 2041
D_j = trips_df['As']  # Projected Trip Destinations in 2041
B_j = [1, 1, 1]  # default matrix to be updated
A_j = [D_j/Ds_j]  # Trip destination / sum of impedance function columns

# Iteration 1
grav = grav.multiply(A_j,axis='columns').multiply(B_j,axis='index')
print(grav)
```

Comment: Is it possible that `A_j = [D_j/Ds_j]` should be `A_j = D_j/Ds_j`?

Comment: Henry's comment is correct^ Thanks Henry